# why changed value with jquery for input not post with form action?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I want to change value of input form with jQuery and then post it a PHP page.

```
<input name="sigName" type="text" value ="" class="form-control" id="picName" required>
```

and

```
$('#picName').val('etc');
```

Value changed and shown on page but when form submitted the `$this->input->post("sigName")`is return `null` in codeigniter.

Any idea for solve this ?

Comment: why vote dislike? please answer

Comment: Your issue may be that you need to try `$_POST['sigName']`. The use of `[ ]` and not `()`.

Answer (score 0):

dude, try changing $_POST("sigName") to $_POST['sigName'].

if that doesn't work, check if you're sending any data to your php file with:

var_dump($_POST);